# I'm trying to make a wordle clone, but can't get it to function properly. Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, event-handling, dom-events

```
let body = document.querySelector("body")
let container = document.querySelector("#container")
let enter = document.querySelector("#enter")



let inputArr = []
for (let rowCount = 0; rowCount < 6; rowCount++) {
  let row = []
  inputArr.push(row)

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let space = document.createElement("input");
    container.appendChild(space)
    row.push(space); 
    space.classList.add("square")
  }
}


let wordSet = ["panic", "knobs", "swain", "dupes", "venom", "great", "carom", "soare"]

let num = Math.floor(Math.random()*8)
let word = wordSet[num]
console.log(word)

enter.addEventListener("click", () => {

  for (let rowVal = 0; rowVal < 6; rowVal++) {
  for (let col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
    let current = inputArr[rowVal][col].value
    
    if (current === "" || inputArr[rowVal][col].style.backgroundColor !== "darkgray") {
      rowVal++
    }

    

      if (current == word[col]) {
      inputArr[rowVal][col].style.backgroundColor = "green" 
    }

       if (current !== word[col] && word.indexOf(current)) {
        inputArr[rowVal][col].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
      }

       if (current !== word[col] && word.indexOf(current) == false) {
        inputArr[rowVal][col].style.backgroundColor = "white"
      }

    
    
  }
}
  
})
```

Whenever I type in some letters into the spaces and press the enter button, the colors of squares in other rows change, and it seems to be in a diagonal fashion. I tried messing around with the if statements, and changing them to else if statements, and I feel like that could have to do with why the wordle clone isn't working, but I'm still not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
 word.indexOf(current) == false
```

indexOf returns the index or -1.

```
-1 == false // false
```

Comment: so are you saying to put -1 in the place of false?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean